# FindRoot over a domain, but give domain boundary if no root exists

Tags: warning-messages, equation-solving, error-trapping

I call

```
r = x /. FindRoot[f[x] == 0, {x, 0, -5, 5}]
```

`f[x]` is always monotonic, but sometimes it doesn't have a root in the specified interval (–5, 5), so I might, for instance, get the error

```
FindRoot::reged: "The point {5} is at the edge of the search region...
```

Rather than raising an error, I would like simply to assign the value `5` to `r` in this case. Likewise, if FindRoot hits the *left* edge of the region without finding a root, I would like to assign the value `-5` to `r`.

Using `Check[…]` would allow me to determine if the *`reged`* error has *occurred*, but that is not enough information to solve this problem; in order to set `r` to the correct value, I need the additional fact of whether FindRoot ran into the *left* edge of the region or the *right* edge.

Comment: having an example f[x] will help.

Comment: Since $f$ is monotonic, you can just pick the endpoint which has the smaller absolute value of $f$. As a bonus, you can do this without needing to call `FindRoot` because that's just going to produce an error anyway.

Comment: @Rahul I don't understand your second sentence. Please note the "sometimes" in the original post—I still want `r` to be the location of the root if FindRoot actually finds one. However, your first sentence is spot-on; feel free to post it as an answer!

Comment: Sorry, "because" should have been "when": If both endpoints have the same sign, that's when you can pick the appropriate endpoint without calling `FindRoot`.

Comment: Actually FindRoot returns the edge-value in case of an error by default (at least in Mathematica 10)

Comment: @funnypony I only get an error message—no solution—in 9.

Comment: @funnypony Wait, you're totally right. I'd had a semicolon stuck on there before suppressing the output! Welp, time for bed, methinks.

Comment: Is there a **Closed: OP is incredibly stupid** category? If not, I guess you can feel free to post "It already does that by itself, doofus" as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested by the OP: *"It already does that by itself, doofus"* :)

Comment: `MinimalBy` is new to Mma 10, in which @funnypony claims the functionality I desire is the default behavior of `FindRoot` anyhow, and so requires no special solution. I myself am still using Mma 9.

Comment: Actually, I've come to realize that @funnypony was right, and FindRoot *does* do what I want automatically, rendering the whole question moot. This answer should still be correct, just totally unnecessary.

Comment: That's what I get for answering on my phone, I suppose. Fixed now :)